# GIT Hook - Compile SASS

Tags: css, git, sass, githooks

At the moment, i'm using an external SASS compiler, and committing my compiled CSS.

So far, no real issues.. until another developer starts work on the site. We've had numerous issues with CSS being merged incorrectly, which is just awful.

I've been looking at using a git hook, to compile SASS on a push, meaning no more CSS merge issues.

I've had zero luck with this, been trying to use the following as a base:

```
    if [[ $1 = "rebase" ]]; then  
    echo "\nRebuiling compiled files post $1..."

    YOUR SASS BUILD SCRIPT HERE

    echo "Adding built files to the last commit"
    git add -u
    git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Does anyone have any useful articles they've used to get this working? Any tips or pointers? Greatly appreciated if so!

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're committing your compiled file(s). Best practice is to commit your source files only and let the deployment do the compiling.

Comment: @jerrylow the reason is i'm unsure how to let the deployment do the compiling unfortunately

Comment: What's your current deployment strategy?

Comment: At the moment, it's just using SSH to push to a server, using separate branches for large pieces of work. All SASS is complied locally outside of GIT

Comment: forgot to tag you @jerrylow, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not committing your compiled CSS because it clutters your repo/pull requests and bound to run into conflict issues. The best option is to ignore the file(s). With your current deployment strategy I can see two options for you.

**Method 1:** Is to manually compile the files on the server. Given you're doing manual SSH deployment anyways. If you're using compass:

```
$ ssh server
$ git pull
$ compass compile
$ rm -R scss/
```

**Method 2:** The other option with git hooks is to use the post-receive hook on a git server setup (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) + https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks,

then you'll have a `post-receive` hook file on your server as such:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Compiling CSS..."
compass compile
rm -R scss/
echo "Compiling CSS Done"
```

Both methods would solve the compile CSS issue. I'd recommend using an continuous integration (CI) tool to deploy. These tools monitor a branch for changes such as master. I've used Travis where I can compile all my SASS there and have it copy it to the server (example):

```
before_install:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
  - sudo apt-get clean
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -y apache2 libapache2-mod-fastcgi
  - gem update --system
  - gem --version
  - rvm install 2.4.2
  - rvmsudo gem install sass
  - rvmsudo gem install susy
  - rvmsudo gem install compass
  - rvmsudo gem install autoprefixer-rails
  - composer global require drush/drush:^8.0
```

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer. We aren't using any CI at the moment, but definitely something we can look at in the coming weeks. When you say $ compass compile
$ rm -R scss/ , where is this set up to connect to my SASS files? sorry it's just a bit confusing to me

Comment: Oh, so that's built in. 

So if I just run compass compile and then rm -R scss/ (scss to my actual folder) it should work good?

Comment: If you're using compass to compile your SCSS files, but yes what you want on your server is a flat CSS file and the next command just deletes all the source files from your server. Although you don't have to do that (last step not necessary).